# Is there any Debian Distro out there that ships without xorg?

Tags: shell-script, debian, x11, xorg, display-server

I am writing a bash script to help new Linux users install Debian desktop environments easily but most of some packages rely on xorg. I think it might not work properly if no xorg is found on the target user machine. I really need to know if there is a Debian Linux distro without xorg and if any, what do they use?

[Github link](https://github.com/LinuxEuphony/linux-desktop-environment-tool-cli)

Comment: Do you really mean a distro that does not have xorg at all, or one that has it, but is not installed by default?

Comment: Any, check net-install ISO. It comes with minimal preinstalled software. Check NixOS or Guix for more flexible setup.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/

Comment: @roaima I meant one without xorg at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian can be set up without X.org, but the tasks corresponding to all desktop environments which need X.org depend on it (through `task-desktop`). Thus installing the appropriate task-based meta-package, using `tasksel`, will pull in the X.org packages if necessary.

The default desktop environment, GNOME, uses Wayland by default in Debian 10, and it is possible to install that without `xserver-xorg`; this will use `xwayland` to run X applications. But the default setup, using GNOME, still installs X.org.

(If you want to run GNOME with no `xserver-xorg` packages, install the base system with no desktop environment, then run `apt install --no-install-recommends gnome`.)

Comment: I'm assuming installing X-related packages does not mean they have to be _used_. It should, for example, be possible to not start X?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Most setups end up starting a display manager automatically, but they can be disabled, and text logins are still possible (as is starting X manually).

Answer (score 3):

It is totally possible to use (and by extend *have*) a Distro (whether Debian or others) without `xorg` installed.

You can emulate this in a VM or even locally (if you're brave enough) to see what will happen, but really, all it will do is that every packages that have `xorg` as dependencies will either break, or refuse to launch.(and will also install `xorg` if you attempt to reinstall said packages)

Though, it is still an usable state, when you know what you want (though limited to `tty` only).

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible for users on Debian to use Wayland instead of Xorg, although it's not a common configuration.  It's also possible to install a base system without X11, for example, with the netinst CDs (as mentioned above).  I personally always use this method because it's much faster to install a system and then install just the packages I need.

In general, I don't think it's worth worrying about Wayland at this point because most users won't be using it, especially users new to Linux.  The easiest way to install a suitable desktop environment is to use the task-* packages, which will install an Xorg server as long as recommends are enabled, which is probably the best way forward for most users.

Comment: Wayland is the default when using the default DE (GNOME) on Debian 10, the current release.